# Nftables- how to mark qinq (double vlan)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, network-programming, iptables, ebtables

hey i am using Nftables in Ubuntu 16.04 , i am trying to mark packet according to the inner Vlan id (create this rule). so far i have succeed to mark only by the first Vlan id with Nftables in this way:

```
nft add table netdev l2  #create table of type netdev  (layer 2)
nft add chain netdev l2 ingress #create chain
nft add rule netdev l2 ingress vlan id 4092 mark set 5 #if(vlan==4092) {mark 5}
```

how to set the same rule but according to second Vlan id?

Comment: You can use `set` feature of nftables. https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets . Check these test cases to get better idea.            http://git.netfilter.org/nftables/tree/tests/py/bridge/vlan.t.payload.netdev#n219

Comment: can you pleas give an example of double vlan as a rule? i am quite confuse because set is used to change the data

Comment: See there are two things one is `set` (used to set the values) and another is mathematical set like `{element1, element2}`.